# Are the screen-headed robots organic?

Tags: comics, saga

In Saga #1, there appear at least three TV screen-headed "robots":

> [image: TV head bot #1]
>   [image: TV head bot #2]

The second of the two (aptly named Prince Robot IV) engages in some reproductive activities that are typically not associated with inorganic beings (i.e. hanky panky). They appear to have normal humanoid physiology, except for their TV screen heads.

What exactly is this race? Are they androids, cyborgs, or (somehow) organic?

Comment: Dunno, but they look a hell of a lot like the One Electronic from Rice Boy: http://www.rice-boy.com/see/

Answer (score 2):

They are inhabitants of "Robot Kingdom", so they are presumably robots.

Here's what Saga creator had to say (Source: 'Saga': Brian K. Vaughan and Fiona Staples Bring a Stellar Sci-Fi Comic Into the World [Interview] - Mar 14th 2012 By: David Uzumeri)

> **CA**: I love the robot people with television heads, and honestly, the sex scene in the first issue made me laugh out loud. Where'd the 1950s antiquated look of these guys come from and how do they fit into the societal picture of Wreath and Landfall? Are there any particular fantasy stories that influenced your work?
>
> **BKV**: Thank you! I don't know, I've been fascinated with old televisions ever since I started writing for TV, so I'm sure that had something to do with it. I'm not terribly well versed in fantasy, so I'm mostly influenced by my own weird fetishes and observations about the real world.
> Though it's not exactly analogous, I suppose the **Robot Kingdom**'s relationship to Landfall is almost as weird as the United States' current relationship with Saudi Arabia.
> **Regardless, that sex scene is actually vitally important to our larger story,** so I'm grateful that Fiona was deranged enough to show our bluebloods in their (mostly) anatomically correct splendor.

As of right now, there's no information on what kind of robots they are, but one can speculate that, given the general "parenting" angle of the comic discussed by the creator, we might eventually see a Robot baby resulting from this?

Comment: This doesn't really provide any information as to whether or not they're any amount of organic. I'm looking for evidence beyond "robot is in their name."

Answer (score 2):

In more recent issues of Saga, various other characters of a range of species have referred to these characters (often, owing to the story, Prince Robot IV) as 'androids', implying some amount more organic content than 'robots'. Not conclusive, since it might be in-universe slang / misinformation, but it's often got the sound of a military term to it, for what that's worth.