# What are all of the races, and where are they from?

Tags: comics, saga

In Saga #1, we are presented with *numerous* races:

- There's the main characters, a dark-skinned insect-winged lady and a horned man:

  [image: Saga cover]
- There's [the robots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13562/are-the-screen-headed-robots-organic), male human-like feather-winged soldiers, and a talking monkey:

  [image: Robots, feather-wings, talking monkey]
- There's more horned men (given that the main male character speaks the same language, it's likely safe to assume he's of the same race):

  [image: Magic horned dudes]
- There are men with what appear to be bat wings, a man with insect wings, and something handing out fliers with a striped tail:

  [image: Additional races]
- There are both male human-like feather-winged soldiers and insect-winged soldiers:

  [image: Winged soldiers]
- There's more talking bipedal animals (an alligator/crocodile butler this time):

  [image: Talking alligator/crocodile]
- A close-up of a bat-winged man:

  [image: Bat-winged man]
- There's what might be a human male (or equivalent of a human) and the lying cat (which likely isn't sentient, so it's possibly irrelevant here):

  [image: Human-looking man and a lying cat]
- Lastly, there's some sort of horn-headed woman:

  [image: Horned woman]

What are all of the races, and what area of the galaxy are each of these races from?

Comment: This is the 1st issue of a new series.  Apart from where the two main characters are from (Alana from Landfall, Marko from Wreath) nothing else has been revealed yet.

Comment: @Legion600 Since when are questions conditional on an answer? And there's definitely some things in the first issue to indicate at least one male/female pair above are the same race.

Answer (score 1):

In Saga #1, we are presented with *numerous* races:

- There's the main characters, a dark-skinned insect-winged lady and a horned man:

  [image: Saga cover]

This would be [Alana](http://imagecomics.wikia.com/wiki/Alana_(Saga)) (The lady), who is a native of the winged race of the planet Landfall (No name of the race is given). The horned man on the right is her husband, [Marko](http://imagecomics.wikia.com/wiki/Marko_(Saga)) from the moon Wreath which is a satellite of Landfall. (Again no specific race given). The baby depicted in the image is their daughter, Hazel.

- There's [the robots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13562/are-the-screen-headed-robots-organic), male human-like feather-winged soldiers, and a talking monkey:

  [image: Robots, feather-wings, talking monkey]

The robot is Prince Robot IV, a member of the royal family of the Robot Kingdom, which resides on a dwarf planet near Landfall. Race is given as robot. The winged soldiers are more natives of Landfall, as is the talking monkey. (Although I cannot find a name or corroborating page for the character.)

- There's more horned men (given that the main male character speaks the same language, it's likely safe to assume he's of the same race):

  [image: Magic horned dudes]

You are correct. This is the Narrative, more natives of Wreath. All natives of Wreath have horns, and they vary in shape and size. (as can be seen by Marko's father, Barr):

[image]

- There are men with what appear to be bat wings, a man with insect wings, and something handing out fliers with a striped tail:

  [image: Additional races]

More natives of Landfall (As far as those with wings). As can be seen by the original photo above of Alana and this photo, wings come in all type including gossamer dragonfly types:

[image]

- There are both male human-like feather-winged soldiers and insect-winged soldiers:

  [image: Winged soldiers]

More Landfallians.

- There's more talking bipedal animals (an alligator/crocodile butler this time):

  [image: Talking alligator/crocodile]

Unknown. I cannot find any other references, and this character is not listed on the Saga wikia.

- A close-up of a bat-winged man:

  [image: Bat-winged man]

Special Agent Gale, a Landfall Intelligence officer.

- There's what might be a human male (or equivalent of a human) and the lying cat (which likely isn't sentient, so it's possibly irrelevant here):

  [image: Human-looking man and a lying cat]

The humanoid is Billy/Will, a Freelancer (mercenary), and a Lying Cat. The cat can presumed to be at least partially sentient, as it can tell when someone is lying or not.

- Lastly, there's some sort of horn-headed woman:

  [image: Horned woman]

This would be [Vez](http://imagecomics.wikia.com/wiki/Vez_(Saga)), a Wreath leader who wants Alana and Marko killed.

In addition to these, they have introduced many more variants (Such as the Stalk, a multi-eyed being, D. Oswald Heist (A cyclops), etc., however there are no races given and very few actual planets of origin. The tailed cats are also not listed, but given their frequency on Landfall, one could presume that they are also a native Landfall species.